# Is it possible to modify an OpenAI gym state before and during training?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, openai-gym, openai-api

What I would like to do is modify an environment, for example take the Super Mario Bros gym environment, and blur the image that the agent trains on, and see whether a reinforcement learning agent is still capable of learning on these "blurred" states.

Does OpenAI make it possible to do something like this? How would I add a gym environment pre-processing step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to make a wrapper for your gym environment that adds a treatment in the `step()` and `reset()` functions

Here is a bit of code to illustrate the idea :

```
class EnvWrapper(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.env = gym.make("Your-Env-Name")    # The wrapper encapsulates the gym env
    
    def step(self, action):
        obs, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)   # calls the gym env methods
        obs = self._blur(obs)                             # applies your specific treatment
        return obs, reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        obs = self.env.reset()    # same for reset
        return self._blur(obs)

    def _blur(self):
        do_whatever_you_need
```

With this method your do not need to make any change to the original environment, which is generally a good idea